# Rails, rendering partial via JS on page load?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

So I understand how to get partials to render when say a link is clicked, but say I want to start loading the partial after the page renders?

**show.html.erb**

```
<div id="weather"></div>
```

**weather.js.erb**

```
$( "#weather" ).html( "<%= escape_javascript(render( :partial => 'weather' )) %>");
```

**weather.html.erb**

```
<%= Time.now %> # For brevity. This actually does more.
```

**Controller**

```
def weather

  slow_api_request

  respond_to do |format|
    format.js {render :layout => false}
  end
end
```

But so then how can I start the request for the partial after the page loads (because the action is pretty slow to retrieve the data from the API), I'm using rails UJS, I just a bit confused.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should simply add an `ajax` call. Assuming you're using jQuery, just add this kind of scripts in your view:

```
$.ajax({
  type: "GET",
  url: "<%= url_for your_path %>" ,
  success: function(data){
    //if ever there is something more to do (there is also an error handler)
  }
});
```